# batch file that detects keystrokes. how?

Tags: batch-file, keyboard

im designing a collection of video games for the command line (such as deal or no deal, tic tac toe, racing, maze puzzle, connect four, wack a mole, etc.) however it would really make things easier for me if i could make it so that when the user makes a selection (such as what direction to move in the game) , that as soon as they press the arrow keys then it carries out the IF statements that follow. Instead of having to press enter after each selection. something like...

```
:one1
set /p direction1= :
IF %direction1%== {ARROW KEY LEFT} goto two2
IF %direction1%== {ARROW KEY RIGHT} goto three3
IF %direction1%== {ARROW KEY UP} goto four4
IF %direction1%== {ARROW KEY DOWN} goto five5
goto one1
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: WTF has batch to do with FP? It barely has subroutines. Also, you don't want to write a complex program in such a language - write it in a language that has e.g. loops.

Comment: FP means what exactly? and the reason i am using batch for this is because not alot of people have tried making a primitive gui in a batch file before so i thought id try it out :P

Comment: FP means functional programming, which you tagged this as. I removed the tag because delnan is right: this question has nothing to do with functional programming.

Comment: Does the choice command work with Win7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:start

choice /c:HPKM /n "Move with arrow keys"

if "%errorlevel%"=="1" {COMMAND}

if "%errorlevel%"=="2" {COMMAND}

if "%errorlevel%"=="3" {COMMAND}

if "%errorlevel%"=="4" {COMMAND}
```

Comment: How this should work with the arrow keys? It works with `HPKM`

Answer (score 5):

It depends of your windows version.

If you use Vista, you can use **choice** to receive single keys directly, but with pure batch it seems not to be possible to detect the arrow keys.

**EDIT**

```
:one1
choice /c awsd /n /m "MOVE with A S D w"
IF %errorlevel%==1 goto two2
IF %errorlevel%==2 goto three3
IF %errorlevel%==3 goto four4
IF %errorlevel%==4 goto five5
goto one1
```

Comment: hmmm, ive seen some people do it but i didnt understand how to use their script with mine without getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

http://winsupport.org/packages/choice.exe

That is a custom choice that allows for arrow keys to be used.

they are used like so: choice /c:HPKM /n "Move with arrow keys"

The only problem being that you can also use H, P, K and M...