# Batch Keystroking

Tags: batch-file, keystroke

I am making a text-based game in Batch, and I was wondering if you can complete a task if the player presses the Up Arrow Key? I have looked through the help files, and did a Google search, but with no solutions. I can't install any extra software because I use a Windows RT device. Also, if it cannot be done in Batch, can it be done in VBS or Powershell?

Comment: Check out this answer... It seems to be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340191/batch-file-that-detects-keystrokes-how

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks, it does not work with the arrow keys, but I can use W, A, S and D. Sorry for not looking hard enough, my bad.

Comment: Excuse me. You added "[Solved]" to the title (a method not used here), but I don't see the answer to the question: How to detect an Up Arrow key in a batch-file? Note that "you can't, but you may use a different method" is _not_ an answer...

Comment: @Aacini True, but I have moved on from the primitive 'programming language' of Batch

Answer (score 5):

It can be done with powershell, this can also detect the arrow keys.

```
powershell "$key = [Console]::ReadKey($true);Write-Host $key.key;"
```

And this can even detect the control keys

```
powershell "$key = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown'); Write-Host "key= $key.VirtualKeyCode";"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Powershell for it, see [example on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708685/handle-keyboard-interrupt-execute-end-block). I am not sure it is possible to process key presses without external programs.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply use:

```
choice /c wsad /n /m "Press a key."
```

And: `if %errorlevel%==1` to detect `w` and `%errorlevel%==2` to detect `s` and so on

That is a simple way to detect a key being pressed. You can't use batch alone to do this task. You can however use Powershell. Also, if you are on Windows RT you need to update. Get a new PC probably is better.